# wso2 maven issue building platform patch release 4.0.9 - failure to find org.wso2.appfactory:wso2appfactory-parent:pom:1.0.0

Tags: wso2

Steps to reproduce error:

1. svn co https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0
2. cd patch-releases\4.0.9
3. mvn clean

Error:

```
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.appfactory:maven-archetype:1.0.0 (C:\wso2\src\wso2_platform_branch_400\products\appfactory\1.0.0\modules\maven-archetype\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.wso2.appfactory:wso2appfactory-parent:pom:1.0.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 21, column 13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `%SRC_ROOT%\products\appfactory\1.0.0\modules\maven-archetype\pom.xml`, change:

```
<parent>
    ...
    <relativePath>../../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

To:

```
<parent>
    ...
    <relativePath>../../../1.0.0/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```