# What are the steps needed to build WSO2 Carbon Platform Patch Release 4.0.x?

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to build the Carbon Platform from source.

I've tried this:

```
svn co https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0
cd patch-releases\4.0.9
set MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

However, I had hit this problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431254/wso2-maven-issue-building-platform-patch-release-4-0-9-failure-to-find-org-wso)

After fixing that problem, I have now run into this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0:compile (default-compile) on project org.wso2.carbon.message.store: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\wso2\src\wso2_platform_branch_400\components\mediation\message-store\org.wso2.carbon.message.store\4.0.9\src\main\java\org\wso2\c
arbon\message\store\persistence\jms\JMSMessageStore.java:[29,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class MessageStores
[ERROR] location: package org.apache.synapse.message.store
```

I must be doing something wrong - I keep hitting errors at each turn?

**Question**: What are the steps needed to build WSO2 Carbon Platform Patch Release 4.0.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The necessary steps are, (if you want to build patch-release 4.0.x)

1) build orbit 4.0.0/
   Then build orbit/patch-release/4.0.x

2) build kernel 4.0.0/
   Then build kernel/patch-release/4.0.x

3) build platform 4.0.0/
   Then build platform/patch-release/4.0.x

This should work.